# Get Top parent url

Tags: urls, child-pages

I have the following structure:

- TOP PAGE

  - SUB PAGE 1
  - --- SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - --- SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - ---- SUB SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - --- SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - --- SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - ---- SUB SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1

How can I get the TOP PAGE url from any of the SUB PAGES?

For example: Get TOP PAGE url from ---- SUB SUB SUB SUB PAGE 1

With this I can only get the previous page url and not the Top parent ulr

```
        if ( $post->post_parent ) {
            $parent_page_link = get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); // getting parent URL
        }
```

There are many topics with related question but I can not solve my problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in a loop:

```
$p = $post;
while ( $p->post_parent ) {
    $p = get_post( $p->post_parent );
}
$parent_page_link = get_permalink( $p->ID );
```

Another way is to use [`get_ancestors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) function:

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $post->ID, 'page', 'post_type' );
$root = ( ! empty( $ancestors ) ) ? end($ancestors) : $post->ID;
$parent_page_link = get_permalink( $root );
```